# Qt Static Linking not working without msvcrt.dll

Tags: qt

Hello my problem is how to build qt application without need a msvcrt.dll
and builded a exe need msvcrt.dll how to fix? im trying build with /MT commandline argument but not working ineed make a full Standalone Qt application.
Thank you

Comment: Statically build Qt will only statically link the qt libs, everything else you will have to link explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use `./configure -static -static-runtime` for MSVC when building Qt. It will link the windows runtime libraries statically.

```
-static-runtime .... Statically link the C/C++ runtime library.
```

or you use MingW as your compiler. MingW will not have the typical windows runtime dependencies. There may be dependencies, but they are already available on every Windows system.

As far as I know `-static-runtime` is available somewhere from `Qt 5.x`

Comment: Thank You very much! you. You are my savior. :)

Comment: Remember that you need a commerical license if you don't publish your source-code.

Comment: OK how to buy commerical license? im using opensource version?

Comment: You can buy it on www.Qt.io. If you release the source-code of your project or use dynamic linking, you don't need to buy it.